# Is Sao Feng's map magical?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end, on-stranger-tides

The map that Sao Feng's hands to Barbossa and co to go rescue Sparrow from Davy Jones' locker contains many information hidden to strange places, some of them out of this world.

But the map itself seems to be quite a feat of craftmaship: you can fold it yet the 'wheels' inside can be turned with no difficulty and show little wear and tear, and it has some inscriptions in English and Spanish despite being a seemingly old Chinese map. It doesn't seem that the way the wheels are positioned matters much when the map is folded as well.

Plus, the map changes in between movies: for example, Florida wasn't on the map on *At World's End* but shows up, along with Ponce de Leon's trip, on *On Stranger Tides*.

So, was it ever established in-universe that the map was magical as an explanation to the way it works and the changes between movies?